# jQuery to "GET", then "POST", then receive "Response", Ajax, ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post, get

I have a test I am setting up (it is going to be used in a compatible cross browser request way, but we are doing initial testing outside of it). So I have page (a) which has some text, and input for a name, and when you click the button on the page, it sends the name to a db and outputs "'Name', you have successfully entered your name."

Now the test is on page (b) which is just a div and a script to load the contents of page (a) into the div called 'loadingDiv'. These contents are just the html div for page (a) with the buttons, etc.

page (a) functions fine on its own. On page b, though, it loads everything, but when I click to submit the name, nothing actually happens. No page is updated, no db update, nothing. Is there something I am doing wrong or not even doing?

Comment: Is the console showing any error? After you hit the button to save the name

Comment: No, and I think I know why. I never attached an event handler to the html that is imported into the page.

Comment: So you do a Ajax request in you page(b) to add the html of page(a) to a div called "loadingDiv" am i right?

Comment: Yes. This is for a client later in the process, but we are just testing the functionality to begin, so I setup this test. So page (a) has a form. Page (b) loads the form into a div (no iframes). I need to post my name back to my own server (but it has to go through the original page (a). So page (b) needs to send the info to page(A). I think what I need to do, probably because I didn't think hard enough before writing, is to pull the info to page b,

Comment: then post to a with the data, handle it in a, then render the output and send that back to b, yes? Or do I instead of rendering the output, do I send back another object and handle in b.

Comment: I think (a) can do all the stuff but check to who is posting a when is added into b if everything works when a is alone (I mean no in the div of b) maybe the error is the page that a is posting when it is on (b)

Comment: Also check of there are no request errors  on the scripts used by (a) when you do the ajax call.